Matrix derivation for $\frac{\partial Tr(AX^2)}{\partial X}$
Suppose matrix $A,X$ are dimension-$n$ matrices. We have $Tr(AX^2)=\sum_{ijk}a_{ij}x_{jk}x_{ki}$. Can we express $\frac{\partial Tr(AX^2)}{\partial X}$ in a simple way, that is in a matrix form instead of giving values of every entry?
We have $\frac{\partial Tr(X^2)}{\partial X}= 2X^T$ and $\frac{\partial Tr(AX)}{\partial X}= A$. For the 2 dimension case, $\frac{\partial Tr(AX^2)}{\partial X}=[  \begin{matrix} 2a_{11}x_{11}+a_{21}x_{12}+a_{12}x_{21} & a_{11}x_{21}+a_{21}x_{21} \\ a_{11}x_{12}+a_{21}x_{21} & a_{21}x_{12}+a_{12}x_{21}+2a_{22}x_{22} \\ \end{matrix}  ]$. But I don't see how to express it using $A$ and $X$.

$$Tr(A(X+H)^2) = Tr(AX^2) + Tr((AX+XA)H) + Tr(AH^2),$$ so if you equip $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ with the Frobenius inner product, the gradient of $X\mapsto Tr(AX^2)$ is $(AX+XA)^\top$.

Define the Frobenius product by a colon $:$ and utilize it's cyclic property
\begin{align}
{\rm Tr}\left( A^T B C\right) 
&:= A: BC \\
&= AC^T: B \\
&= B^TA:C
\end{align}
Let
\begin{align}
f(X) := {\rm Tr}\left( A X^2\right) = {\rm Tr}\left( A X X\right)  \equiv A^T: X X.
\end{align}
Now, we can use differentials and then obtain gradient.
\begin{align}
df 
&= A^T : dX X +  A^T : X dX \\
&= A^TX^T : dX + X^T A^T: dX 
\end{align}
The gradient is
\begin{align}
G:= \frac{\partial f}{\partial X} = A^TX^T  + X^T A^T = \left(AX + XA\right)^T.
\end{align}
